# can i swap out js files included in my index page if using conditional comments for IE9 Specific

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so basically I have a great site , works in every browser including i.e... except for i.e9 , ouch !

so i figured out I have a few problems with a jquery plugin called multilevelpush.js it is great but simply wont work with i.e9

EDIT :- Basically since i posted this question I have isolated a line of code that seems to stop the menu functions from happening , removing it allows things to work the line of code is this...

```
$( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' );
```

What I need to figure out now is why that works fine in all other browsers except ie9 (and posibly below)... any advice would be helpful.  I kept the whole script for the button below.

```
$('.fa-question-circle').parent().on('click', function () {
      $(".metro").css('background-image','url('+"images/mthc/image2.jpg"+')');
      $('.submenu-ctn').fadeTo(0, 0);
      $("#colorscreen").remove();
      $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' );
      $("body").append('<div id="colorscreen" class="animated"></div>');
      $("#colorscreen").addClass("fadeInUpBigCS");
      $(".tile-area-main").css({opacity:1}).load("what.html .slides.overview");
      $.getScript("js/slider/slider-animations.js");
      $(".submenu-ctn").load("what.html .submenu-what");
      $('.nav-toggle').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');  
      $('.submenu-ctn').fadeTo(3000, 1);

});
```

NOW IT GETS INTERESTING --- EDIT NUMBER 2

I have isolated the lone of code as mentioned above and found a way that makes it work in i.e 9 , it is basically this ...

```
$('#menu').multilevelpushmenu({
        Collapsed: true
    });
```

but all other browsers don't like it so i basically want to do something like this ...

```
('.fa-phone, .bg-darkPink').parent().on('click', function () {
      $('.submenu-ctn').fadeTo(0, 0);
      <<--IF I.E9 OR BELOW DO THIS THING--->>
$('#menu').multilevelpushmenu({
        Collapsed: true
            });
      <<--END OF I.E9 OR BELOW THING ----->>
      $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' );
```

so any ideas on how i might actually build a function to do this ?

Comment: The 'h' tag? You mean head? If so, yes, but won't affect your DOM.

Comment: hah , i was just about to edit my page hang on i found something out ...

Comment: Yes you can use ie conditionals to include separate files.

Comment: thanks buddy , since i figured out that line of code was causing problems i have turned my attention back to getting that code working for ie9 as well... very strange why it doesn't like it

Comment: although admitidly i believe it may of been simply the fact that there were spaces within the braces

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it a lot easier than optionally including another file?

In your own example you're inside JavaScript when you can actually conditionally checking for the presence of IE and either pass in the desired arguments or not as required.

You could add a bit of code to specifically look for IE and then deal with the outcome

```
getNavigator: function() {
  var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
  if (navigator.appName === 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var re = new RegExp('MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})');
    if (re.exec(ua) !== null) {
      rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
    }
  }
  return rv;
}
```

and then do something like this in your code and just set a flag

```
    var version = getNavigator();
    ieMods = (version !== -1 && version <10);
```

and then check that flag inside the click event like this:

```
('.fa-phone, .bg-darkPink').parent().on('click', function () {

    $('.submenu-ctn').fadeTo(0, 0);

    args = (ieMods) ? { Collapsed: true } : 'collapse';
    $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu(args);
```